# Proof and geometrical significance of $F(n+1)^2-F(n) \cdot F(n+2)$?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

My son notes that for Fibonacci numbers $F_n$,
$$
 (F_{n+1})^2-F_n \cdot F_{n+2} =(-1)^n
$$

1. I assume that this is true.
   **Update**:  I see that the proof is already here: [Prove the given property of the Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725597/prove-the-given-property-of-the-fibonacci-numbers) , so never mind about that part.
2. I'm really looking for a good geometrical intuition, since those two terms seem like likely areas in those spiral diagrams.  Is there a direct way to think about this identity geometrically?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/CassinisIdentity.shtml

Comment: Many thanks for the reference, @bburGsamohT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following diagram, the Fibonacci spiral arrangement of squares up to $5^2$:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

I claim that $5^2 = 3\cdot8+1$. This is equivalent to $A+B = A+C+1$, which simplifies to $C = B-1$. In other words, it remains to show that $3^2 = 2\cdot5-1$, and the rest is induction.

Answer (score 1):

$$
 (F_{n+1})^2-F_n \cdot F_{n+2} =(-1)^n
$$

So, I am assuming by the spiral you are referring to the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). deMoivre found a closed-form expression of the Fibonacci numbers.

Binet's Formula:  $F_n=\dfrac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}} $ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio given by $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi=1-\phi=-\dfrac{1}{\phi}$ .

$$\left(\dfrac{\phi^{n+1}-(-\phi)^{-n-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2-\dfrac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\dfrac{\phi^{n+2}-(-\phi)^{-n-2}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Simplifying this expression indeed does give the desired result:

$$(-1)^{n}$$

Note that the golden ratio also satisfies the equation below:

$$\phi^2=\phi+1$$